# loop through an arrary by using Next button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file with a div containing img and the img is coming from my database which is in an arrary. I want to code a "Next" btn, so it loops through the array and display different imgs. But I do not know how to do this by using J.Query and php. Plz give some help. Thx

```
<link href="../css-home/findgoods.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="../js/home-img.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

 <?php if(is_array($goodsinfo)):?>

  <div class="container">         
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
       <img class="img-click" src="<?php echo $goodsinfo[$size] - >goods_pic?>"/>
    </div>


  <button id="call_back_btn">Next</button>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>

    <textarea id="response"></textarea><!--
```

> what I want to do in here, is to change the value $size in my php so that I can loop through my $goodsinfo which is an array; at the start I want to show the first picture in my arrary, so i want $size to be 0 and if press Next button, $size becomes 1 and so on. I tried in two text box, it does change when I click Next, but the $size which got back from the ajax seems not changing.

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
$index = 0,
$itemAmt = 6,
  $.post("../js/calculate_array.php", 
    {
        size : $index,
    },
        function(data)
        {
            $('#response').val(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    );

$('#call_back_btn').click(function()
{
     $index += 1;
      if ($index > itemAmt - 1) {
        $index = 0;
      }
     $.post("../js/calculate_array.php", 
    {

        size : $index,
    },
        function(data)
        {
            $('#response').val(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
    });
});
```

> my ajax file.

```
<?php
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  echo $size;
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain in more clarity? Like giving the array example and returning what value exactly and what the PHP code does with the posted value?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply print all images to the html using php

```
// Array of images names
$images = array('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg');

// Lets go through array and print every image
for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
  // If not first image, set display to "none"
  $display = $i === 0 ? '' : 'style="display:none"';
  echo('<img class="multiple-images" src="'.$images[$i].'" '.$display.'>');
}
```

So only the first image will be visible and rest will be hidden.
Next create javascript function that will display next image.

```
// Find all images we want to cycle through
var images = $(".multiple-images");
var next = function() {
  // Find current displayed image with class ".active"
  var current = images.filter(".active");
  // If none image was found, use the first one
  if(current.length == 0) current = images.eq(0);

  // Find next image (element) after the current one
  var next = current.next();
  // If none was found, it means we are currently displaying last image
  // and there isn't any next image, so use the first one
  if(next.length == 0) next = images.eq(0);

  // Remove ".active" class from images
  // Here, we could also remove class only from "current"
  // but just to make sure there isn't multiple images with current
  // class, use this
  images.removeClass("active");

  // Hide currently displayed image
  current.hide();

  // Show next image
  next.addClass("active").show();
}
```

Now just assign `next` javascript function to your button

```
$(".my-button").click(next);
```

Few tips to improve script:

- you could update php script, so that instead of assigning `style` attribute with display none to images, you could assign class `active` to first image
- then you could update your css so that all images would be hidden except the one with `.active` class
- you could pass some argument to `hide` and `show` functions if you want a transition effect between images

Comment: hi, I tried it and it works. but I want to know how is the script working.  Could you talk me through? thanks

Comment: I have updated an answer, take a look :) ... also, take a look at [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) to better understand jQuery functions, they are all very well documented with examples, PS: accept the answer if it's what you were lookin for ;)